# Programming laptop available in Greece?

Tags: laptop

I need to buy a new laptop for my programming job. The problem is that I just don’t like laptops! I have to get this because I need to travel and meet with colleagues and have to do some work on site. This implies that there is a good chance that this is not going to be my main computer in the future.

On the other hand, I don't want to waste money (even the smallest amount) on a laptop that will be garbage in a year or so. If I have it I will use it, for as long as it lasts.

My main jobs are performed in Eclipse, Netbeans and Android Studio. From what I have read around, these do not support multi-threading. So Intel would work better than AMD since (again from what I understood on the web) AMD has more cores, but single core speed of AMD is lower than that of Intel's. If I am using programs that can only use one core at a time then Intel should work better, right?

The main problem is that I am in Greece, and I have to buy it from a store here, since it will have to go to my expenses. So I am guessing that not all models might be available here.

Requirements:

- CPU: a decent one that will last for some years (thinking i5 5200U)
- RAM: I am guessing 4GB for budget reasons, but would be nice to have extra slots for future upgrades if needed
- Monitor: Would love a 17inch for ease of work, but (at least in the Greek market) 17' come with a lot of power that skyrocket the price. plus most I have seen come with HD, not FullHD, resulting a more or less the same effect (do you agree with that?)
- Storage: not important since I will use my desktop for any file storage/backup
- Cost: It will be hard to help me on this one since prices are much different in every country, but I am guessing something in the 500-600 Euro range (US$560-640)
- Must be available in Greece

Bonus question:
Is an i3 with SSD as good as an i5 with HDD? some guy (that I trust) told me that, but I am not so sure I believe it.

**Edit:**
What about this:
HP 15-ac011nv - 15.6" 
(i7-5500U/4GB/500GB/HD 5500)

- CPU   Intel Core i7-5500U 2.40 GHz
- cache     4 MB
- RAM   4 GB - DDR3 SDRAM - 1600 MHz
- HDD   500 GB
- monitor   15.6" BrightView WLED - 1366x768
- Graphics  Intel HD Graphics 5500 - Shared Memory
- 2 x USB 2.0, 1 x USB 3.0

The ram might need some boosting. Will call them soon to ask the max ram that i can install, and how much an extra 4 costs.

The price for some reason (ok i know 2, will see it in a sec) the price is really low for an I7 550 Euro
The only drawback it seems that it is the low resolution screen and the GPU. I am not going to play any games on this anyway, nor i will watch any 4K movies.
how about this then?

**update**
I did got the HP after all.
It seems like a good one, i was disappointed that it's not easy to get the hdd out easily, since i have an extra ssd that i want to install instead.

Comment: Your bonus question doesn't really make sense. The processor and the disk are two separate and distinct parts of the system - an i5 is a better processor and it's debatable which of HDD and SSD is better, but comparing compounds of each is a strange prospect.

Comment: @ArtOfCode This guys reasoning, was that if the disc writes the output of the cpu faster, then the cpu will be free sooner, thus moving to the next process/thread

Comment: I can sort of see that, but bear in mind that the CPU output isn't always written to disk.

Comment: Actually, AMD tends to also have higher clock speeds. I think the biggest difference is that intel is just more efficient.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Clock speed is rather irrelevant if the IPC doubled on the same (or similar, anyway) ISA.

Comment: “if the disc writes the output of the cpu faster, then the cpu will be free sooner” [It doesn't work like that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access) (well, to some extent it does, but it has nothing to do with how fast the storage medium is, rather with the communication protocol between the storage controller and the main CPU, and that doesn't depend on HDD vs SDD). *Read* speed does matter in practice because often the CPU has nothing useful to do (no other process is doing anything at the moment) until it has read the data.

Comment: “I am guessing 4GB” With Java development environments, go for 8GB if at all possible.

Comment: Note that if you need this device mostly for travel and claim you won't be using it much for non-travel work, maybe you should consider something  smaller than 15"? Smaller devices are easier for transport.

Comment: Do you mean it the other way round by sny chance? If i don't need it for travel i would get bigger than 15", but i haven't found a mid range 17" model, they are either cheaper ones (eith celeron) or hogh end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skroutz is your friend :-P

- Intel i5 5200U 2.2GHz CPU
- 15.6" LED LCD screen
- 4GB DDR3 RAM
- HD Graphics 5500
- 1TB HDD

http://www.skroutz.gr/s/6738402/Lenovo-G50-80-i5-5200U-4GB-1TB-W8.html

Comment: I know ;) This is the one i was looking at to be honest. Should i go for that or go the extra mile and get an i7? that is the 900Euro question:)

Comment: That is up to you. Depends how much you are willing to spend on it. If it is 300 euro for an upgrade to i7 only, I would say forget it. Too much for the upgrade, unless there is an upgrade on the RAM or HDD included. Read this link where they are being compared. The difference between the specific i5 and i7 isn't great.  http://www.ultrabookreview.com/6135-intel-core-i5-5200u-i7-5500u/

Comment: Btw, if you think this is the best answer please mark it as correct. Struggling to get points around here... Xairetismous apo Agglia :-P